# Extract elements of matrix from a starting element and size

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

Sorry about the bad title, I'm struggling to word this question well. Basically what I want to do is extract elements from a 2d matrix, from row by row, taking out a number of elements (N) starting at a particular column (k). In for loops, this would look like.

```
A = magic(6);
k = [2,2,3,3,4,4]; % for example
N = 3;
for j = 1:length(A)
    B(j,:) = A(j,k(j):k(j)+N-1);
end
```

I figure there must be a neater way to do it than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `bsxfun` to create an array of indices to use. Then combine this with the row numbers and pass it to `sub2ind`.

```
inds = sub2ind(size(A), repmat(1:size(A, 1), 3, 1), bsxfun(@plus, k, (0:(N-1))')).';
B = A(inds);
```

Or alternately without `sub2ind` (but slightly more cryptic).

```
B = A(bsxfun(@plus, 1:size(A,1), ((bsxfun(@plus, k, (0:(N-1)).')-1) * size(A,1))).');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using [`bsxfun's`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) masking capability and thus [`logical indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) -

```
C = (1:size(A,2))';
At = A.';
B = reshape(At(bsxfun(@ge,C,k) & bsxfun(@lt,C,k+N)),N,[]).';
```